# Regular expression to replace all superscripts in R

Tags: r, regex, superscript

Although there's a lot of examples and questions about regexp in R none of them seems to be proper for my problem. In my project I'm struggling with strings like the one "4x1²+1x1²". Superscript characters seem to be very problematic for me.

My goal: from `4x1²+1x1²` I want to get `4x1^+1x1^`. Just replace all superscripts with "^". Easy, yes?
I found a pattern for that "\p{No}" but I'm afraid it's not working in R or I'm using it incorrectly.

What I tried:

```
my_string <- "4x1²+1x1²"
patt <- "\\p{No}"
gsub(patt, my_string, replacement = "^") # error
gsub(patt, my_string, replacement = "^", perl = TRUE)
stringr::str_replace_all(my_string, patt, "^")
```

Nothing works. Do You have any ideas on how to replace the superscripts?

### EDIT:

I'm working on Windows. I tried to run those commands on Linux and it worked. Seems like it must be related to system settings or R session settings.

Comment: `gsub(patt, my_string, replacement = "^", perl = TRUE)` works for me, returns `"4x1^+1x1^"`

Comment: Now I'm a little bit confused... Can You share the output from `pcre_config()` call?

Comment: `UTF-8 :TRUE, Unicode properties :TRUE, JIT :FALSE ,stack : FALSE `

Comment: @RonakShah thanks. I run it on Linux and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows: `chartr("²", "^", "4x1²+1x1²")
`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
my_string <- "4x1²+1x1²"
gsub("[⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]", "^", my_string)
```

Or, using `\u{XXXX}` notation (tested in Windows):

```
gsub("[\u{2070}\u{00B9}\u{00B2}\u{00B3}\u{2074}-\u{2079}]", "^", my_string)
```

Or, a PCRE based `gsub` like

```
gsub("[\\x{2070}\\x{B9}\\x{B2}\\x{B3}\\x{2074}-\\x{2079}]", "^", my_string, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/UPrQDp) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ySzNUM/2).

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to ASCII, replace and convert to UTF8:

```
> utf8ToInt("²")
[1] 178
> utf8ToInt("^")
[1] 94
> intToUtf8(sapply(utf8ToInt(my_string), function(x) ifelse(x == 178L, 94L, x)))
[1] "4x1^+1x1^"
```

Comment: That's interesting - I get `utf8ToInt("²") = 50`on Windows and `utf8ToInt("²") = 178` on Linux. Apparently, it's not a matter of invalid regexp but rather system configuration.

Comment: So just use `intToUtf8(sapply(utf8ToInt(my_string), function(x) ifelse(x == utf8ToInt("²"), utf8ToInt("^"), x)))` and it should be OS independent.

Comment: This won't work because it will replace all occurrences of digit 2 with "^". For example, I run Your code on the string `"222 4x1²+1x1²"` and it produced `"^^^ 4x1^+1x1^"`. It's because the problematic superscript "²" is detected as digit 2 (the code is 50, not 178).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
library(stirngr)
str <- "4x1²+1x1²"
str_replace_all(str, "²", "\\^")
#[1] "4x1^+1x1^"
```